# How to validate phone number in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to validate the field of phone number and allow only numbers that start with the following digits 77, 71 , 73 .

How can I implement that in the request that I created?

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required|min:6',
            'phone'=>'required|digits:9',
        ];
    }
```

Comment: If you require 9 digits, then what is the meaning of a minimum of 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would to use regex.

```
 'phone' => ['required', 'regex:/^((71)|(73)|(77))[0-9]{7}/']
```

1. I assume your phone number has 9 digits so I used {7} 
   // (71|73|77)2 digits + 7 digits = 9 digits
2. Notice when you want to use OR, you should use an array instead of separating rules using |

Answer (score 2):

You should just a regex solution here, e.g.

```js
var numbers = [771234567, 128675309];
console.log(/^(?:71|73|77)\d{7}$/.test(numbers[0]));
console.log(/^(?:71|73|77)\d{7}$/.test(numbers[1]));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to validate a phone number like :

```
'phone' => 'required|regex:/(01)[0-9]{9}/'
```

This will check the input starts with 01 and is followed by 9 numbers. By using regex you don't need the numeric or size validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers given are excellent but it depends on the country used as phones varies from country to country for example in Nigeria we validate phone number like

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required|min:6',
            'phone'=>'required|regex:/^(080|091|090|070|081)+[0-9]{8}$/',
        ];
    }
```